# rendering and saving images through Blender python

Tags: python, render, save, blender

I am trying to render and save multiple images through python script in blender. I know how to render and save the image through the Blender GUI but I want to do it all through my script since I am using a set of nested loops and need to save multiple images. I am able to render the image and I guess save the image with the output being successful. But I am not sure where it saves to and when I try to edit the filepath it gives me the error of the context being incorrect.

Comment: This would be better on Blender stack exchange.

Answer (score 56):

The code below creates a "VR panorama" *(a series of pictures of an object, from different perspectives around it)*.

I ended up with this algorithm:

1. create or load an object you are going to take pictures of (the *subject*)
2. scale it and add some nice lighting *(so that the object is visible from directions you want)*; you can check the lighting by rendering the scene *(using the <kbd>F12</kbd> key)*
3. <del>create an `Empty` object and set its position to the center of the subject and rotation to identity (`0, 0, 0`)</del>
4. set your camera view to the starting position *(check it with rendering, again)*
5. open interactive Python shell (<kbd>Shift+F4</kbd>)
6. paste & run the script

You shall end up with a number of pictures *(defined by `rotation_steps`)* around your object under `/Users/myusername/Pictures/VR` directory:

```py
def rotate_and_render(output_dir, output_file_pattern_string = 'render%d.jpg', rotation_steps = 32, rotation_angle = 360.0, subject = bpy.context.object):
  import os
  original_rotation = subject.rotation_euler
  for step in range(0, rotation_steps):
    subject.rotation_euler[2] = radians(step * (rotation_angle / rotation_steps))
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = os.path.join(output_dir, (output_file_pattern_string % step))
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still = True)
  subject.rotation_euler = original_rotation

rotate_and_render('/Users/myusername/Pictures/VR', 'render%d.jpg')
```

You will have to select the object you want to render. Alternatively, you can use [Blender's Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_quickstart.html#accessing-collections) to find the object in the scene and pass it as a `subject` param to the function:

```py
rotate_and_render('/Users/myusername/Pictures/VR', 'render%d.jpg', subject = bpy.data.objects["Cube"])
```

Comment: Wondering why `write_still=True` is so crucial that you don't have an image saved without it.

Comment: @SibbsGambling I think it's because Blender also has an option to render preview images (much like when you press F12). So actually saving the render as a still image is somewhat optional.

Comment: After a w while I _almost_ got this to work. Just one problem: All the generated images are identical :-). It seems like the line "origin.rotation_euler[2] = radians(step * (rotation_angle / rotation_steps))
   " is doing exactly nothing

Comment: need these: import os, import bpy, from math import radians

Answer (score 13):

something like this:

```
import bpy

bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = 'pathToOutputImage'
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = w #perhaps set resolution in code
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = h
bpy.ops.render.render()
```

Comment: Without 'write_still=True' as parameter for the 'render()' function blender did not create an image in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do the following. The `i` in the second line after the `for` loop is the loop index of the file loop.

I have verified that this works while running in the console and also from the command line. Don't forget to remove the objects after you render one file. (The remove command is not given here since it is not generic. Some specific arguments will be needed in that command if that object has links)

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        area.spaces[0].viewport_shade = 'RENDERED'

bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format='JPEG'
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = ".pic%0.2d.jpg"%i
bpy.ops.render.render(use_viewport = True, write_still=True)
```