# How can I capture view from another program into opencv?

Tags: opencv, screen-capture

I have a 3D model of an object and I need to view it in some program and then capture this view by OpenCV so that I can move the model in a program and capture an image of this moving object in OpenCV. Do you know any easy way to do it? Also could you recommend some good program to view the 3D model in (I have .obj model).

What I need to get at the end is being able to process the image from the 3D-model program in OpenCV.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand how you can be manipulating 3D models if you don't know any programs that manipulate 3D models? Nor I am sure what it is exactly what you want to capture, but if you mean screen-grabs, you can try `pyautogui`.

Comment: I mean I know some programs. For now I use Blender (not only for viewing). But maybe there are some other programs witch which it will be easier. What I want to capture are the screen-grabs from the viewing program.

Comment: Blender supports Python scripts, so it might be possible to handle it from there. For example [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/80481) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53150750/10699171). If that proves too difficult, I would advise a screengrab from pyautogui.